# creating Dict, how to update when looping

Tags: python, dictionary

i am looping through a file directory, when i come across a file with some specific text i want to add the file name and modified time to a dictionary, based on my dir i should end up with 7 key, value pairs in my dict.

how do i keep adding key,value pairs to my dict while i loop this dir?  thanks

```
import os
import stat

path =r"C:\Users\Gronk\Downloads"

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if 'ConsensusData' in file:
        info = os.stat( path+"\\"+file)
        t = info.st_atime
        x = {}
        x.update({file:t})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the dictionary outside the `for` loop, and add `key`/`value` pairs as `dict[key]=value`:

```
x = {}
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if 'ConsensusData' in file:
        info = os.stat( path+"\\"+file)
        t = info.st_atime
        x[file] = t
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use setdefault method:

```
x = {}
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if 'ConsensusData' in file:
        info = os.stat( path+"\\"+file)
        t = info.st_atime
        x.setdefault(file, t)
```

Comment: thanks rusu. this works. i wasnt aware of 'setdefault'